# Lock cell after 1st edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a Google Sheet which get auto-populated by google finance.
I wish to lock two cell BB and BC for edit after the first value is fetched. This cell locking should be done permanently for these two cells even for the creator/owner. The other cells must be open for edit or addition.

I tried this code

```
function protectOnEdit(event) {

  var range = event.range;
  var Col= parseInt(range.getColumn());
  console.log(Col);
  
  if(Col==54)
  {
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description);

 
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  //user who installed trigger

  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
if(Col==55)
  {
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description);

 
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  //user who installed trigger

  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}

}
```

It seems to attempts to lock the cells but since I am the owner, it becomes ineffective in locking the cell as it also edits to me.

Pls suggest change in the code to achieve the above.

Comment: According to the docs, you cannot remove the owner of the sheet or the current user from the editors list. A potential workaround is to reset the value to the old value in the onEdit trigger function. Something like `if(e.range.oldValue !== e.range.value) e.range.setValue(e.range.oldValue);`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50989441/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55432383/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner would be able to edit the protected cell, but there is something that you can do. First of all you would need to store the *true value* of the cell (the one that you want to keep) in [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#saving_data). This should be done as a script property, since you want every user to be able to access this *true value*. You can store them in a key/value fashion, so different cells can be identified easily. 30.95

Now that the *true value* is stored, you only need to restore it after each edit. Even if the owner edits the protected cell, you can set up an `onEdit()` trigger that first checks if the edit is done on the protected cell and then restores the cell to the *true value*. I see in your code that you already check if the range matches the protected one, so you only need to add some lines that overwrite the edition with the *true value*. See the example below and drop a comment if you need me to clarify this approach.

```js
event.range.setValue(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(
  'My protected value #1'));
```

## UPDATE

To set up the `PropertiesService` and save some data on it you can use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('KEY', 'Value')`. Then you can read that property with `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('KEY')`. Here is an example:

```js
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('AVERROES_BIRTHDAY',
  '14 April');
var birthday = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('AVERROES_BIRTHDAY');
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#saving_data) you can see more examples.

Comment: I appreciate your help and elaborate explanation. However I am a novice and dont know how to set the Propertiesservices etc.
I request  you to provide me with a stepwise procedure if time permits you.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Rinku. I have just updated my answer, check the example and let me know if you find any difficulties.